# Count number of ratings

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate number of every rating group by given date range. I wrote the following query which is working perfect:

```
SELECT c.day, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ratings r WHERE DATE(r.created_at) = c.day AND r.rating = 1 AND r.campaign_id = 2) AS rating1s,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ratings r WHERE DATE(r.created_at) = c.day AND r.rating = 2 AND r.campaign_id = 2) AS rating2s,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ratings r WHERE DATE(r.created_at) = c.day AND r.rating = 3 AND r.campaign_id = 2) AS rating3s,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ratings r WHERE DATE(r.created_at) = c.day AND r.rating = 4 AND r.campaign_id = 2) AS rating4s,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM ratings r WHERE DATE(r.created_at) = c.day AND r.rating = 5 AND r.campaign_id = 2) AS rating5s
FROM calendar c
WHERE c.day >= '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY c.day
ORDER BY c.day
LIMIT 0, 31
```

But this is not an optimized way due to 5 sub queries and query is taking almost 2mins on my localhost, how can I optimize this query? The sample output is attached and I need same output.
[image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - although, if it was me, I'd handle this kind of thing in application code.

Comment: I just don't see why this is attracting downvotes or votes to close.

Answer (score 1):

You can rephrase this as conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(r.created_at),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.rating = 1 THEN r.user_id END) as raging_1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.rating = 2 THEN r.user_id END) as raging_2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.rating = 3 THEN r.user_id END) as raging_3,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.rating = 4 THEN r.user_id END) as raging_4,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.rating = 5 THEN r.user_id END) as raging_5
FROM ratings r
WHERE r.campaign_id = 2 AND
      r.created_at >= '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY DATE(r.created_at);
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` can be expensive.  Remove it if you can. 
 Otherwise, it might be faster to do the `DISTINCT` once:

```
SELECT dte,
       SUM( r.rating = 1 ) as raging_1,
       SUM( r.rating = 2 ) as raging_2,
       SUM( r.rating = 3 ) as raging_3,
       SUM( r.rating = 4 ) as raging_4,
       SUM( r.rating = 5 ) as raging_5
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, rating, DATE(r.created_at) as dte
      FROM ratings r
      WHERE r.campaign_id = 2 AND
            r.created_at >= '2018-08-01'
     ) urd
GROUP BY dte;
```

This returns rows for each day that has at least one rating.  If some days would have all zeroes, then you'll need an outer join of some sort.  That adds almost nothing to the performance, so it can be tacked on if one of the above solutions works.

Comment: In addition, depending on the data, there might need to be an `outer join` coming from the `calendar` table.

Comment: Thank you for your idea but unfortunately it does not work in mysql, I made some changes from your idea which is working

Comment: @UmairHamid . . . These queries should work in MySQL.  The first had a syntax error, because I left out the `END`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query I made using @Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT  DATE(r.created_at),
       COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE 
             WHEN r.rating = 1 
             THEN  user_id
             ELSE 0
           END
       ) as rating1s,
       COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE 
             WHEN r.rating = 2 
             THEN  user_id
             ELSE 0
           END
       ) as rating2s,
       COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE 
             WHEN r.rating = 3 
             THEN  user_id
             ELSE 0
           END
       ) as rating3s,
       COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE 
             WHEN r.rating = 4
             THEN  user_id
             ELSE 0
           END
       ) as rating4s,
       COUNT(
           DISTINCT
           CASE 
             WHEN r.rating = 5 
             THEN  user_id
             ELSE 0
           END
       ) as rating5s

FROM ratings r
WHERE r.campaign_id = 2 AND
      DATE(r.created_at) >= '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY DATE(r.created_at)
```

This is still not optimized but much better than my initial solution.